# How do I replicate a randomly generated map of connected rooms to multiplayer in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: c++, replication, unreal-engine4, multiplayer

Currently both players have a completely differently randomly generated rooms made in c++, since the exits of each room are different for both players, when player one walks out of the first room, player two will see them trying to walk into a wall. How do I replicate this randomly map? I'm hard stuck :(

Comment: `auto the_copy = the_original_map;`?

Comment: sadly the map isn't stored as anything, walls and floors are pieced together using a "GeneraterRooms()" function

Comment: Then I suggest that you rearrange the code so that `auto the_copy = the_original_map;` works. If that seems infeasable, please show a [mre] and someone might be able to help with that.